# Unable to take input with Scanner class

Tags: java

See the code below, in this code I want to declare the Scanner class instance again and again for every input instance, I know I can declare the Scanner class instance outside the loop and the problem will be solved. But I am only showing you how I am implementing the same concept some where else. I cannot write that code here that's why I want you people top give me solution by understanding my perspective.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestScanner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a[] = new int[4];

        System.out.println("Enter elements in array: ");

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            a[i] = scanner.nextInt();
            scanner.close();
        }

        System.out.println("The Arrays is : ");

        for (int i : a) {
            System.out.println(i + "  ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that when you close the scanner, it also closes the underlying stream, in your case `System.in`. Thus you're unable to take a new input.

Comment: @Alexis C so should i not close the scanner close at all ??

Comment: If you have a question about an exception, then please add that exception (+ stacktrace) to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the line `scanner.close();` because it disables taking in new input through `System.in`. You will still need `scanner` in each iteration of the `for` loop.

Comment: but then a warning is always left that you need to close the Scanner class, i want to get rid of that.

Comment: Sometimes it is okay to not close it and ignore the warning. It would depend on your situation. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919143/is-it-safe-not-to-close-a-java-scanner-provided-i-close-the-underlying-readable

Comment: okay i will use your suggestion and thanks for your contribution

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your code like this. You can reuse the `scanner` object inside your loop, no need to create one per iteration.

```
Scanner scanner;
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
   scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
   a[i] = scanner.nextInt();
}
scanner.close();
```

Comment: Afaik, the `System.in` is automatically closed by the JVM, so closing the scanner in unnecessary in this case (Please correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: I guess you are right. Its optional to close a `System.in`.

Comment: @redflar3 you didn't understood the scenario

Comment: oops.. my bad, didn't read the post fully... in your case you can just ignoring the closing of `System.in`.

Comment: @redflar3 but that causes a warning to be left in IDE, cant that be cleared

Comment: you can suppress the warning using annotation.. make sure to give it with the lowest scope; also, When ever you do that, you can make sure to give proper comments/documentation on why you are sure to suppress the warning (as a good practice).

Comment: @KrishanAggarwal add `@SuppressWarning("resource")` above the method, or the scanner declaration. This is one of the rare time where ignoring a warning is OK.

Comment: @KrishanAggarwal have you gone thru
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25506240/how-to-close-a-scanner-without-closing-the-underlying-system-in

Comment: Also is any possibility of dependency injection in your scenario?